# Pass variable from URL to PHP to Javascript and Display Value in Input Field

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, parameter-passing

I have an email subscriber form that I'm trying to pre-populate with an email address (which will show up in the form).

The email address to use is included in the URL

```
http://www.domain.com/page?email=joe@emailaccount.com
```

The input field in the form is:

```
<input class="text" id="awf_field-48578149" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501"  />
```

The page is on a site running Wordpress as the CMS, so I don't want to execute PHP using an "allow PHP" plugin due to security issues.  I tried creating a custom PHP page template and including language to assign the variable in PHP and then HTML via javascript.

First, I created a custom-page.php page template including the following:

```
<?php
/*
Get email from URL and set to email1 variable
*/
$email1 = $_GET['email'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var email2 = <?php echo json_encode($email1); ?>;
    document.getElementById("awf_field-48578149").value = email2;
</script>
```

Next, I included the form code on a Wordpress page using the custom-page.php template.

The challenge is to get the variable value to show up in the input box when the page loads (pre-populated).

I'm by absolutely no means a coder, but would appreciate help. Any ideas?

Here's the form code (on the Wordpress page using the template):

```
<!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0 -->
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="787465482" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="mhpc001" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=text" id="redirect_3b0dde6df528b65fe85ebedf277b6e10" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="Existing_Owner" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<div id="af-form-787465482" class="af-form"><div id="af-header-787465482" class="af-header"><div class="bodyText"><p>&nbsp;</p></div></div>
<div id="af-body-787465482"  class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-48578148">Name: </label>
<div class="af-textWrap">
<input id="awf_field-48578148" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  tabindex="500" />
</div>
<div class="af-clear"></div></div>
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-48578149">Email: </label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-48578149" type="text" name="email" tabindex="501"  />
</div><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer">
<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="502" />
<div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=7BzsLGysLBxM" alt="" /></div>
</form>

<!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0 -->
```

Comment: The most elegant solution would be one where the id value can change (since the email service provider provides a unique value for each email opt-in form you create), but for now just being able to pre-populate and show the email value would be great.

Comment: Why are you using json_encode, and why are'nt you just echoing the value straight into the form after validating it as an email ?

Comment: The form is not in the template, it's on the page using the template, so I can't use <?php echo $email1; ?> because I can't execute PHP code on the page.  I'm using json_encode based on another answer I saw for a similar situation.  I'm not a coder, so I'm hacking this together.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var email2 = "<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>";
    document.getElementById("awf_field-48578149").value = email2;
</script>
```

Comment: Would I omit the value="" field in the input field?  If so, how will it show the value assigned?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't display the value for the email in the form input box.

Comment: Second line of code is setting `input`'s value. I have no idea why it doesn't work for you. Any errors in javascript console? Are you sure that `$_GET['email']` is not empty?

Comment: Yes, there's an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" displayed right below document.getElement... when I use the code:
`<script type="text/javascript">
    var email2 = "<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>";
    document.getElementById("awf_field-48578149").value = email2;
</script>`

Comment: Both script and form are in the same file, right? You should put this script in head section of page, or right before `</body>`. It seems that `DOM` isn't loaded when your script is executed.

Comment: I believe they are since the page is using the template that has the script.  The form is on the page.  I experimented and put the script below the form, which then filled in the form.  It's as if the script is loading but not seeing the form since it's lower on the page.

Comment: Be careful with this. What if `$_GET['email']` contains this? `"; document.location = "http://myevildomain.com/do/bad/things`? You need to validate the data *and* sanitize before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in  :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ //code here });
```

This will make the browser wait to execute the code until the page has finished loading.  Also, you may want to think about make sure the string passed to the Javascript is only an email address and not code to protect yourself from cross-site scripting.